# Delete remaining debris (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I don't need code (it would be appreciated, but not a must), just an opinion...

I am working on an image cleaner. Given this image...

[image: src]

...can you clean it more than it actually is using OpenCV and Python ? It is possible without touching the quality of the written characters ?

I don't think you need the code I used, BTW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156711/fill-detected-blobs-opencv-python/47157299#47157299) you can see it.
For now it's just simple blob removing which works for the most of the images I have.

There is other I can do or I should consider the cleaning complete ?

This is the source image I am working on:

[image: src2]

In my opinion is pretty good the result I achieved. What do you think ?

The image would be used in chars recognition, just to know..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some good progress cleaning it up. Another thing you could do is to remove the smallest blobs (might affect the dot on 'i' and 'j' though). You could also remove any other blobs that are a thin horizontal line.

Comment: doing it just now...will update the post with new images ASAP.